# How does AppArmor match profiles to processes?

Tags: apparmor

What are all the ways AppArmor profiles can be matched to processes? One seems to be path based (e.g. the `/sbin/dhclient` profile is applied when `/sbin/dhclient` is executed) but is this due to `/sbin/dhclient` appearing in the `sbin.dhclient` profile or because of the way `sbin.dhclient` is named?

Also, for non-path based profile matching (e.g. for the `docker-default` profile) how is AppArmor told which processes to apply the profile to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AppArmor profiles using a mangled path of the command for the filename is just a convention. From [`man 7 apparmor`](https://manpages.debian.org/stretch/apparmor/apparmor.7.en.html):

> Profiles are traditionally stored in files in `/etc/apparmor.d/` under
>   filenames with the convention of replacing the `/` in pathnames with `.`
>   (except for the root `/`) so profiles are easier to manage (e.g. the
>   `/usr/sbin/nscd` profile would be named `usr.sbin.nscd`).

The profile name, if it contains a file glob, applies to files matched by that glob. From [the AppArmor Core Policy Reference](https://gitlab.com/apparmor/apparmor/wikis/AppArmor_Core_Policy_Reference#profile-names-and-attachment-specifications):

> The attachment specification is used by AppArmor to determine which
>   executables a profile will attach to. If alternate profile name is not
>   supplied the attachment specification is also used as the profiles
>   name and if an attachment specification is not specified a profile
>   name must be provided.
>
> The name of a profile is very import in AppArmor. It provides not only
>   a name(s) that users can associate to the set of profile rules, but is
>   also used for labeling, ipc, and in the case that the name is an
>   attachment specification it determines to which executables the
>   profile attaches.

Comment: what about the `docker-default` profile or other non-path based profile names?

Comment: What about them?